# `cp` vs `rsync` vs something faster

Tags: linux, macos, docker, rsync, cp

I am using Docker and Docker cannot `COPY` symlinked files into the image. But the files that are symlinked are not in the 'build context'. So I was going to copy them into the build context with cp, but that's really slow. Is there some way to share the files on two different locations on disk without have to copy them and without using symlinks?

Comment: If they are on the same physical partition, use a hard link.

Comment: Pls add an answer for maximum gains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed and it won't be

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1676

> We do not allow this because it's not repeatable. A symlink on your machine is the not the same as my machine and the same Dockerfile would produce two different results. Also having symlinks to /etc/paasswd would cause issues because it would link the host files and not your local files.

If you have common files which are needed in every container then I would put all of them in a shared image and use docker multi build options

```
FROM mysharedimage as shared

FROM alpine
COPY --from=shared /my/common/stuff /common
....
```

Again still not the most elegant solution but, because when you do docker build the current context is zipped and sent to the docker daemon, soft links won't work.

You can create hard links but then hard links point to inodes and they don't show you which file they point to. Soft links on other tell you where they point to but the build doesn't sent them.

```
ln /source/file /dest/file
```

So your call really what you want to do and how you want to.

Comment: Hard links absolutely show you which file they link to.  By definition, they are a link to a file.  If `/path/to/foo` and `/path/to/bar` are both links to the same file, then they both link to the same file.  If you want to know which file they both point to, check.  There is literally no reason to think of one of the links as the "real" file; they both reference the same thing.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, what i meant is that `ls -alh` will not show you that the file is pointing to some other file. Which means you will have to check `inode` and find if some other file also refers to that inode. Am i missing something that in that understanding?

Comment: `ls -l` will show you the link count for each file.  It is (typically) the 2nd column of output.  I am mostly taking exception to your use phrases like "some other file".  If you do `ln a b` to create a link `b` in the current directory, then `a` and `b` both reference the same file.  It is incorrect to think that `a` is the file and `b` is a reference to it.  `a` and `b` are different names for the same file, and there is no difference between them other than the name.  In other words, `b` is not pointing to "some other file" and more than `a` is.  Each of them is a link to a file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, yes that is per my understanding as well. The only thing i meant to say was that `ls -alh` doesn't show the file location in hard links, because it is now a inode reference. So I am not sure what is the easiest way to track these locations, so if a file has 10 count shown in `ls -al`, then how do i know which all paths points to this inode. May be you can enlighten me on that.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't show the file location in hard links"?  In particular, what do you mean by "location"?  The point I am belaboring is that `/some/path/a` is neither more nor less the location than `/other/path/b`.