# Shared code library between Docker containers

Tags: python, docker, web-services, dockerfile

I've seen a related question from 2017 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135315/cp-vs-rsync-vs-something-faster) and the linked GitHub discussion from 2014 [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1676), but this behavior really doesn't make sense to me and I'd like to know if there is any good workaround for it.

Currently, I'm working on a project which has a single git repository as the root directory and multiple subdirectories which each contain a service I'm running in separate docker containers. This has worked well up until now since there was not any shared code between these services, however, as projects evolve requirements change and I've created a small code library which I'd like to share between two services. This library is not big enough to warrent something like a git submodule, but it's not small enough that I would want to have to make all updates twice if the code were duplicated.

ex. In the project root, I have two directories `Foo` and `Bar` which will both contain a support library `FooBar`. The directory structure I would like is then something like this:

```
<root>
|
+- Foo
|  |
|  +- FooBar
|  |
|  +- Dockerfile
|
+- Bar
|  |
|  +- FooBar
|  |
|  +- Dockerfile
```

where `FooBar` contains the same source files in both instances. My instinctive solution here is to simply create a symlink, ex. `Foo/FooBar` is a link to `../Bar/FooBar` where the source reside. As per the linked question/discussion, this is not supported. The reasoning given in the GitHub discussion does make sense, if the symlink could point anywhere on the host system, I can imagine many bad outcomes would be possible, but in my specific instance, these two services will never be deployed separately and the symlink simply points to another docker image's source. If I setup the symlinks as I want, the Dockerfile COPY command seems to just copy the link as-is, so it becomes a dead link in the destination image. I would prefer it follow the symlink and copy the file itself.

I'm not an expert on the workings of docker, and while I've read some of the documentation, it's totally possible that I missed an easy solution to this problem. Is there any way for me to setup this directory structure so that there is only a single master copy of the shared code which can be referenced from both of my services? These specific services are developed in Python and the `FooBar` library is a python module if that makes any difference.

Comment: Too much text. Please focus on the actual question!

Comment: Submodules are the way to go. Alternatively you can `pip install` your dependencies from your private Git repo but it's more work (you'll need to set up a GitHub secret key and somehow inject it to the Docker build environment).

Comment: I'd try packaging the shared code into a module that can then be imported into the projects that need it. Based on my personal experience, I'd avoid git submodules if I could.

Answer (score 1):

The important detail here is that a Dockerfile can never `COPY` anything into an image from a parent or sibling directory.  This means you need to build an image starting from the nearest ancestor directory that contains everything you need to include; in your case, the root of the source tree.

```bash
# foo/Dockerfile
FROM something
COPY common/ /app/common/
COPY foo/ /app/foo/
WORKDIR /app/foo
...
```

```
# in a shell, at the root of the source tree
docker build -f foo/Dockerfile .
```

Note here that the left-hand side of `COPY` is relative to the path argument to `docker build`, the `.` at the very end, and not to the location of the Dockerfile.

Once you've done this, inside the image, from the `/app/foo` directory, there will be a `../common` directory reachable as a relative path, and if you `COPY` a symlink into the image or `RUN ln -s` it will work the way you expect.

From your description you make it sound like the common library code isn't that large or that complex.  This approach will give each image a separate copy of it, but for a small and simple library that shouldn't be a practical problem.  If the applications themselves are small you could just build one image containing everything together and run it with different commands; this may or may not be practical.

Also note that nothing here involves Git or any other source-control system; it is only based on the files that actually exist on the host system.  You can manage these in whatever way you want to.